# Python: How to Slice & Index Chunks of a List into a New List

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, slice

Let's say I have the following list:

```
nums = [10,2,3,4, 8, 3]
```

I want to slice and index nums so that I create a new list from only some elements of the original list.  For example #1:

```
nums_1 = [10, 3, 4, 8, 3]
```

Or Example 2:

```
nums_2 = [10, 3, 4, 3]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?  I tried nums.pop() but I don't want to change the original list.

Comment: How are you selecting which items go into the new list?

Comment: "I want to slice " Okay, so: figure out the rules that tell you what slices to use; make them; and put them together. What is the difficulty?

Comment: If, for example, you want "how can I make a new list with every element except the one at a specified index?", I think there is a more specific duplicate for that. If you want to exclude multiple specific indices, that is applying the same technique multiple times, or else Needs More Focus to be answerable.